# Unfortunately, <app name> has stopped "String data = sharedData.getText().toString();"

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Good morning guys!

Quick question, I am using file Input/Output in Java to save data into a String when the "Save" Button in my program is pressed. But whenever I hit the "Save" button, the program stops working.

I am also new to Java and Android, so I can't really tell yet if the problem is very specific to my code or a more general one which is why I am posting this question even if there are many others that are similar.

Using comment-outs "//, /*,  */" I was able to locate the line in my code that causes the program to stop working, I have emphasised this line by placing "*" at the beginning and at the end of it so you won't have trouble looking for it. I just want to know why this line is causing my app to stop and if possible, how it can be fixed.

Thanks guys. Your assistance will be very much appreciated.

Please take a look at my code snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText sharedData;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    String FILENAME = "InternalString";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurants);
        adapter = new RestaurantAdapter();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    public View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener (){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Info r = new Info();

            EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_name);
            EditText address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_address);
            TextView total= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
            RadioGroup types = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgrp_types);
            switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.rbtn_sit_down:
                r.setType("sit_down");
                break;
            case R.id.rbtn_take_out:
                r.setType("take_out");
                break;
            }

            r.setName(name.getText().toString());
            r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());
            r.setTotal(total.getText().toString());

                String data = sharedData.getText().toString();*** <----- This line causes it to stop running

            try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String collected = null;
            FileInputStream fis = null;

            try {
                fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
                byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
                while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1){
                collected = new String(dataArray);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                    total.setText("Balance Total: " + collected +"Php");
            }   catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            Log.d("FoodTripActivity", "Name: " + r.getName() + "Address: " + r.getAddress() + "Type: " + r.getType());
            adapter.add(r);

        }               
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sharedData` is not initialized. You need to initialize it before calling `getText`.

You have only declared it `EditText sharedData;`

```
sharedData =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.idforshareddata);
String data = sharedData.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Let me give this a try, i'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: @SandyBites it will work provided you have a edittext with the id in your xml layout that you set to the activity

Comment: I added an id for sharedData in the xml layout, however it still stops working when I hit save. I wonder why.

Comment: @SandyBites post stacktrace.

Comment: It's the same line as earlier. String data = sharedData.getText().toString(); I apologize im pretty new to Android and Java and am not familiar with the term stacktrace, is it the information inside LogCat? Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @SandyBites same line causes error meaning its not initialized properly. My answer still stands. `sharedData` is null

Comment: Yes, I have added the line you have suggested.     EditText sharedData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sharedData);
   String data = sharedData.getText().toString(); also, I have added an id for sharedData in the xml layout file. Somehow it still comes up with the same problem..

Comment: @SandyBitesAFAIK it can only be null if initialization fails. That is only reason and you have not initialized it properly. Also clean and build the app

Comment: OK, let me work on getting it initialized properly. But thanks for the assistance. Cheers.